# A problem on unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{R})$. Suppose there exists an unitary matrix $U \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$U^{-1}AU = B.$$ Show that there exists invertible symmetric $S \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$S^{-1}AS = B \text{ and } S^{-1}A^TS = B^T,$$ where $A^T, B^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

I understands that this is a simple problem, but I spent quite a lot of time without any meaningful result. So, please bear with me if any one found it too simple.

OK, let's talk about what I have done. Since the question requires $S$ to be real, the first thing I thought of is to consider $S = \frac{1}{2}(U + \overline{U})$ or $S = \frac{1}{2i}(U - \overline{U})$. But the problem comes immediately: How can I ensure $S$ to be orthogonal in this case? Since this method does not seem to work, I then think how about $S = \frac{1}{2}(U + U^*)$ or $S = \frac{1}{2i}(U - U^*)$? Since $U$ is unitary, at least one of them is invertible. Moreover, $S$ will then be self-adjoint. Nevertheless, the catch is we do not have $S$ to be a real matrix. Finally, I just try to form some matrices coming from $U$ and doing some manipulations on the original equation and nothing comes from it.

So, is there any hint anyone could give me? I will highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like $S$ is supposed to be orthogonal

Comment: Consider $S=UP$ polar decomposition of $S$ which is unique w.r.t $U$.